# Where can I get the source for CommonNavigator?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've installed the Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources, but it doesn't seem to include the Source for Common Navigator. Is there something else I'm supposed to install?

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the `Eclipse Platform SDK` install along with all the rest of the core Eclipse source.

Once you have this installed you can go to `Preferences / Plug-in Development` and check the `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search` option. This will allow the `Open Type...` dialog to search the Eclipse source for classes. This assumes that your `target platform` is the Eclipse code.